# Доступ к методам Java класса

Tags: jsp, java, jstl

Имеется информационный класс `Java` под именем `Data` с полем `date` типа `java.util.Date` и метод `getDisplayDate(Date date)`, преобразующий дату в короткий формат "ДД.ММ" для визуализации на `JSP` странице.
Объект данного класса передается на страницу `Jsp` через `request`.

Как, используя теги `jsp:useBean`, `jsp:setProperty`, `jsp:getProperty`, воспользоваться методом `getDisploayDate` и отобразить информацию в приемлемом виде?

Перебирая возможные варианты, для себя сделал вывод, что ни через библиотеку `JSTL`(можно `${data.date}`, но нельзя `${data.getDisplayDate(date)}`) ни через `JspBean` невозможно воспользоваться методом `Java` класса не имеющем в самом классе информационного поля с таким же именем, однако для меня вариант создания нового поля с короткой датой неприемлем.

Как другими вариантами достичь цели?

Comment: ну и формулировка первого абзаца...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

если вам нельзя изменять этот класс - напишите custom tag. Подключили бы библиотеку fmt, получится что то типа

```
<fmt:formatDate value="${data.date}" pattern="dd.MM"/>
```

на jsp странице.

Comment: Спасибо, работает!

Comment: @rvm, почитайте спецификацию по java bean и что в нем должно быть, и поймете почему простые методы нельзя вызвать.

Answer (score 0):

Наверно тебе надо юзать что-то типа

```
private final static String PATTERN = "EEE, MMM d, ''yy";
private SimpleDateFormat formater = new SimpleDateFormat(PATTERN);

formater.format(date)
```

и возвращать куда надо )